# failure to login tradingview (tvDatafeed) thu python

Tags: python, authentication, tradingview-api

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval
tv = TvDatafeed('username', 'password')
```

Once I run the code, it show

> error while signin
> you are using nologin method, data you access may be limited

My username and password are all correct since I can login to [www.tradingview.com](http://www.tradingview.com) directly.

I have tried the remove or add ' during programming too.

Could someone comment or help me to solve this "login tradingview" problem?

Comment: I am also getting the same error, were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: TradingView support is bad.  I have encountered this problem too, I can log in successfully using Python, but suddenly the system stopped working, and despite numerous attempts to log in again at different time slots, I have been unsuccessful.

Given that I am a paid user of TradingView, I reached out to their customer support for assistance. Unfortunately, my experience with the customer support representative, James B, was disappointing. He closed the chat box message and did not provide the level of support and assistance that I expected in resolving my login issues.